# Shared variable reset formula in header doesn't cause formula in footer to reset

Tags: crystal-reports, shared-variable

I have this formula in the group footer and it counts accurately.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
shared NumberVar cCount := COUNT({history_client_charge.clientNo});
```

Then I put this formula in the group header but it doesn't cause my variable to reset.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;

shared NumberVar cCount := 0;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried without "WhilePrintingRecords"? Anyways, do you think a running total field would do the work?

Comment: I need to count only visible records. Would the running total field work for that?

Comment: It is possible. Create a formula that make the record visible or invisible. Something like "@isVisible". Use this formula to suppress the record (the detail section?). Then use the same formula in the "running total field" / "evaluate" / "use a formula". Let me know if you need more explanation. Rememebr to "reset" it "on change of group".

Comment: I tried that. It said I can't run a running total on a prime time formula, which is my only method of hiding records.